# Scala Play WS.put Array[Bytes] setting negative bytes to 0b111111

Tags: java, scala, http, playframework

I am doing a HTTP put of an Array[Byte] using Play's web service client. For some reason, it is setting negative bytes to 63 (0b111111). I sent the same byte stream using Java's HTTP stuff and it sent over the Byte Array properly. Any hints?

Here is an example:

```
    //Play Web service send bytes
    val bytes = Array[Byte](0, -3, 2, ...)
    WS.url(httpService).put(bytes)


    //java send bytes
    val j = new URL(httpService)
    val con = j.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
    con.setDoOutput(true)
    con.setRequestMethod("PUT")
    val out = con.getOutputStream.asInstanceOf[ByteArrayOutputStream]
    out.write(bytes)
    out.close()

    val input = con.getInputStream
    while (input.available() > 0) input.read()

    input.close()
    con.disconnect()
```

Comment: Please, show us some code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the character set to **iso-8859-1**. In general it is better to use base64 to send a byte array over the line; however, I couldn't in the context of this problem. Below is an example of the solution. Note, I was setting the Content type to application/octet-stream before and it didn't work. The fix was the charset=iso-8859-1 addition.

```
  WS.url(url).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/octet-stream;charset=iso-8859-1")
```